# Lp space Inclusion Examples

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I proved for a bounded set $\Omega$ and $1 \leq p \leq q \leq \infty$ that $L^{q}(\Omega) \subset L^{p}(\Omega)$. What is an example that would show strict inclusion, $ p<q$, and false if $\Omega$ is not bounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\in L^2([1,+\infty))$, but it does not belong to $L^1([1,+\infty))$

Comment: I see, since  $\int_{1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{x})^{2} dx=1$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{x}) dx$ does not exist.

Comment: Why $\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx$ does not exist? It's improper integral and it diverges. It's value is $+\infty$

Comment: Sorry for the misuse of language, when I said "does not exist" I meant diverges or tends to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

For $1\leq  p<q<\infty ,\quad  $ $f(x)=x^{-1/q} $ belongs to $L^p(0,1)$ but not to $L^q(0,1)$.

Comment: NIce, so this would make the Inclusion stronger.

Comment: I recall an exam Q : Prove, for $1 <q<\infty$, that $\cup_{1\leq p<q}L^p[0,1]\ne L^q[0,1].$

Comment: I think it was the other way around :Show that $\cap_{q>p}L^q[0,1]\ne L^p[0,1].$

Comment: Are you saying, that for the example you provided $f(x) \epsilon L^{q}(0,1)$ but $f(x)$ does not belong to $L^{p}(0,1)$?

Comment: i will get back to you after the Super Bowl.